# Sending variable from one function to another

Tags: php

Basically, I have two functions as shown below, the first function checks if the pickup is an airport address (which is being sent via ajax from jquery function). If it is an airport basically I want to send the variable $fare from getAirportFare function to getFinalFare function, so that it adds a charge if it is an airport address. I was just wondering how I would do this? (still trying to learn PHP)

Any help would be much appreciated.

```
//DEBUG//

public function getAirportFare($fare, $fieldAirport) {

if ($fieldAirport == 'airport') {

    $fare = $fare + 50.00;

    return $fare;

    }

}

//END OF DEBUG//

private static function getFinalFare($fare) {

    $final_fare = ($fare * self::$fare_factor);

    if (self::$str_wait_return == "true") {
        $final_fare = $final_fare * 2;
    }

    if (self::$str_return == "true" && self::$return_date != "false" && self::$return_time != "false") {

        // We need to calc to fare based on the return date and time
        $return_fare = self::getFare(1);

        // Append to final fare
        $final_fare = $final_fare + $return_fare;

    }

    // Create new journey object with the info that we have so far

    /*$journey = new Journey($journey_id,$pickup,$dropoff,$vias,$distance,$vehicle,
                    $date_time,$return_journey,$meet_greet,$extras);*/

    return number_format($final_fare,2);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand this correctly, it's as simple as this:

```
//DEBUG//

public function getAirportFare($fare, $fieldAirport) {

if ($fieldAirport == 'airport') {

    $fare = $fare + 50.00;

    // Send the fare to the getFinalFare function and assign it's result.
    $final_fare = self::getFinalFare($fare);
    return $final_fare;

    }

}
```

Let me know if I haven't answered your question.

Comment: `getFinalFare` is a static function. You can not call it as `$this->getFinalFare`, instead use `self::getFinalFare`

Answer (score 0):

To send a variable from one function to another (or from an instance method to a static method, as you're doing here), call the second function within the first function, and pass it the variable as an argument, like so:

```
public function getAirportFare($fare, $fieldAirport) {

   if ($fieldAirport == 'airport') {

     $fare = $fare + 50.00;

     return self::getFinalFare($fare); 

    }

 }
```

Your instance method will now return the return value of your static method.

Answer (score -2):

I believe you must declare `global $fare` outside the function, and when use inside it, use `$this->fare`.